# Using Next.js specific features in a ui library published as npm package

Tags: next.js, widget, npm-publish, next-router, next-images

I have a published Ui-component/Widget library. For the images in the Widgets I would like to use next/image. But when starting the app that consumes my library im getting the error:

`error - Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'path\to\node_modules\next\image' imported from path\to\node_modules\@mynpmpackage\public-widgets\index.js Did you mean to import next/image.js? at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5) at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:418:11) at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:983:10) at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1080:11) at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:530:30) at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:251:18) at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:79:40) at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:78:36) { code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND', page: '/' }`

My installed npm package has the correct peerDependency set to `"next": ">13.1.0"` the consuming application has also the correct npm package `"next": "13.1.6"` installed.

Now im questioning my approach if this is even possible to do, and if so what i need to be aware of when using Nextjs features like useRouter/Image in my component library.

I have tried different packages which all worked fine, just subpackages of next like: next/image or next/router dont work.

Comment: I'm hitting exactly this problem. I know it's a long time ago, but do you remember if/how you resolved it?

Comment: I fixed it by making my library framework agnostic, i added slots where the consumer of my component library could replace the component "Image" as configuration for my package. same for the router functionalities.

Comment: Oooh, that's a good idea, it entirely side-steps the problem. I paused this work in the hope that a solution would present itself, this solution fits the bill perfectly. Thank you!